# Batch processing a list in Wikidata Query Service via command line (wdq)

Tags: bash, sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to extract names and death dates of certain people from a list by querying Wikidata with the wdq command.

I was hoping to achieve this with the following command on Bash Shell:

`while read line; do wdq 'SELECT * WHERE { ?person rdfs:label "$line"@en; wdt:P1559 ?name_in_native_language; wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath. }'; done < people_list.txt`

where `people_list.txt` is a list of people's names and surnames, one per line.

What I get at the moment is a `not found` string for any item of the list.

Where am I getting this wrong?

Comment: you can easily debug it if you print (`echo`) the query string and see if this is correctly build in your loop. So my question, how does a query string look like when printing it? Also, "not found" - is `wdq` in the PATH of your current terminal/user? Or better said, what is "not found" - is it a bash error or a query error?

Comment: wdq is in the PATH, the "not found" seem to be query errors.
Also can I ask how to echo the query string as you suggested? (sorry I am quite a beginner)

Comment: I'd say just do `echo 'SELECT * WHERE { ?person rdfs:label "$line"@en; wdt:P1559 ?name_in_native_language; wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath. }'`

Comment: also, you can see a difference if you use single quotes inside double quotes: `echo "SELECT * WHERE { ?person rdfs:label '$line'@en; wdt:P1559 ?name_in_native_language; wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath. }"` - here the variable `line` will be inlined, in your case it won't, thus, the query is wrong

Comment: so, can you try `while read line; do wdq "SELECT * WHERE { ?person rdfs:label '$line'@en; wdt:P1559 ?name_in_native_language; wdt:P570 ?dateOfDeath. }"; done < people_list.txt`

Comment: It works, those double quotes instead of single quotes were the main issue. Thank you so much!